# How do you get shared_ptr weak count?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, tr1

Is it possible to get the weak reference count to a shared_ptr?  I know how I can get the shared_ptr use count using

```
std::shared_ptr::use_count
```

but I would like to know if there are any non-implementation specific ways to get the number of weak_count references?

Comment: There's none. At most, there might be a way many implementations happen to support.

Comment: What is the real problem you're trying to solve? (And also note the standard puts no performance constraints on `use_count` either `[20.7.2.2.5/8]`).

Comment: @MarkB: I am interested in this too; since there is no way to prevent someone else to create another reference concurrently...

Comment: Even if you could get to the weak reference count, it's unlikely to be useful because the value is implementation dependent. A library may choose to implement it as `weak_count = num_weak_refs + (use_count > 0)` or `weak_count = num_weak_refs + use_count`

Comment: I'm just exploring options to prevent shared_ptr cycles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in C++11, and not in [this draft](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3797.pdf) of C++14.

Answer (score -1):

No, remember that weak_ptrs are just observers rather than an actual pointer to the object they are not designed to return their counts.